# Rearrange an array to users desires

Tags: arrays, powershell

Apologies if asked and answered already.
I'm making a custom application leveraging pdftk to merge a handful of documents.  I'm trying to implement a method to arrange an array similar to

```
$pdfArray = Get-Childitem Full\Pathname | where name -like "*.pdf"
```

I need to devise a way for my user to be able to rearrange that array such that when the array is passed into the pdftk.exe /cat $pdfarray /output $outputname the docs are merged in the desired order (dont quote me on the command at all, just trying to illustrate the point).  Im not above making the users name their files in such a way that its sortable but if i could make it easy for them to click move up/move down like a common pdf application would be ideal.  Any ideas on a good approach?

Comment: The question is not really clear. How would the user be rearranging the names?

Comment: through some form of a Listbox.  While im halfway proficient in powershell I really dont get a chance to play with forms/visual studio often enough to know what question i need to google to get the answer im looking for.  I would like for users to be able to click-drag or use a move up-move down

Comment: Easiest way to accomplish this is a ListBox with Up & Down buttons.

Comment: ty, researching it now.  ironically it wasnt until @Bill_Stewart asked me to clarify the idea hit me.  thank you guys for getting the wheel turning

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, why don't you write it up as an answer, get some rep, and get this out of our unanswered filters? :)

Comment: Look, in this [form](https://github.com/santysq/SimpleQueryUI/blob/main/Dependencies/Forms/propsForm.ps1) I'm using a listBox with an 'Add All' & 'Remove All' buttons, i'ts not exactly the same as what you need but can get you started.